# What languages are supported for nltk.word_tokenize and nltk.pos_tag

Tags: nlp, nltk

I need to conduct name entity extraction for text in multiple languages: spanish, portuguese, greek, czech, chinese.

Is there somewhere a list of all supported languages for these two functions? And is there a method to use other corpora so that these languages can be included?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070105/pos-for-languages-other-than-english has some pointers for getting POS tagger support for languages other than English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, both functions only support English text. It's not really in the documentation but you can see it by looking at the source code:

1. The `pos_tag()` function loads a tagger from the this file:    `'taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle'`. ([see here](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag.html#pos_tag))
2. The `word_tokenize()` function uses the Treebank tokenizer which uses regular expressions to tokenize text as in the (English) Penn Treebank Corpus. ([see here](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html?highlight=treebankwordtokenizer#nltk.tokenize.treebank.TreebankWordTokenizer))

Comment: But the word_tokenize works well with western languages. Does it mean that i can use it but not for languages that dont separate words with spaces?

Comment: They explain the algorithm [here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenization.html). As Western languages usually seperate by space it should work fine. I've only tried it for German and it looked okay.

Answer (score 14):

The list of the languages supported by the NLTK tokenizer is as follows:

- 'czech'
- 'danish'
- 'dutch'
- 'english'
- 'estonian'
- 'finnish'
- 'french'
- 'german'
- 'greek'
- 'italian'
- 'norwegian'
- 'polish'
- 'portuguese'
- 'russian'
- 'slovene',
- 'spanish'
- 'swedish'
- 'turkish'

It corresponds to the pickles stored in C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\tokenizers\punkt (in Windows). This is what you enter with the key 'language' when tokenizing, e.g.

```
nltk.word_tokenize(text, language='italian')
```