# POS for languages other than English

Tags: python, nltk

Im very new to nltk.

This allows me to tag a sentence according to its parts of speech. But what steps are involved when doing this for other languages?

```
import nltk
sentence = "I'm not sure!"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
```

**UPDATE**

I am interested at starting with Spanish.

**UPDATE 2**

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

training_set = [[(w.lower(),t) for w,t in s] for s in nltk.corpus.conll2002.tagged_sents('esp.train')]

unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(training_set)
bigram_tagger = nltk.BigramTagger(train_set, backoff=unigram_tagger)

tokens = [token.lower() for token in word_tokenize("El Congreso no podrá hacer ninguna ley con respecto al establecimiento de la religión, ni prohibiendo la libre práctica de la misma; ni limitando la libertad de expresión, ni de prensa; ni el derecho a la asamblea pacífica de las personas, ni de solicitar al gobierno una compensación de agravios.")]
```

Producing:

```
[('el', 'DA'), ('congreso', 'NC'), ('no', 'RN'), ('podrá', 'VMI'), ('hacer', 'VMN'), ('ninguna', 'DI'), ('ley', 'NC'), ('con', 'SP'), ('respecto', 'NC'), ('al', 'SP'), ('establecimiento', 'NC'), ('de', 'SP'), ('la', 'DA'), ('religión', 'NC'), (',', 'Fc'), ('ni', 'CC'), ('prohibiendo', None), ('la', 'DA'), ('libre', 'AQ'), ('práctica', 'NC'), ('de', 'SP'), ('la', 'DA'), ('misma', 'DI'), (';', 'Fx'), ('ni', 'CC'), ('limitando', None), ('la', 'DA'), ('libertad', 'NC'), ('de', 'SP'), ('expresión', 'NC'), (',', 'Fc'), ('ni', 'CC'), ('de', 'SP'), ('prensa', 'NC'), (';', 'Fx'), ('ni', 'CC'), ('el', 'DA'), ('derecho', 'NC'), ('a', 'SP'), ('la', 'DA'), ('asamblea', 'NC'), ('pacífica', 'AQ'), ('de', 'SP'), ('las', 'DA'), ('personas', 'NC'), (',', 'Fc'), ('ni', 'CC'), ('de', 'SP'), ('solicitar', 'VMN'), ('al', 'SP'), ('gobierno', 'NC'), ('una', 'DI'), ('compensación', 'NC'), ('de', 'SP'), ('agravios', None), ('.', 'Fp')]
```

Comment: Your other language still looks a lot like English to me (but I'm not sure).

Comment: To be serious: It really depends on the language, and the task. For tokenisation, NLTK supports a number of languages out-of-the box – just add the language as the second argument to `word_tokenize()`. For POS tagging, you need to create a tagger object with the language-specific model (which you might even have to obtain from a third-party site); there's no single answer to that, you need to specify the languages in question.

Comment: @lenz I have updated my question as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik the nltk does not come with ready to use taggers or parsers  for any languages other than English. There are such tools outside the nltk, which you could download and use.

The nltk does provide the tools to train your own tagger for Spanish, using one of the Spanish tagged corpora as training material. For example, you could follow the nltk's instructions for [building a tagger](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html#automatic-tagging) but use `conll2002.tagged_sents("esp.train")` as the training data. It's only about 250K words so you won't get great performance, but it should get you started. (And of course you can find yourself a larger tagged corpus to train with.)

Comment: Should a tagger be trained differently if I wish to tag sentences or if I wish to tag words on their own. For example, when I have trained the tagger, will it be able to establish that "hacia" is a preposition without the context of a sentence?

Comment: Have I done things correctly according to my second update in my original question?

Comment: Not bad, but your solution can't tag unknown words (what the default tagger is for). Test your tagger by calling its `evaluate()` method on `conll2002.tagged_sents("esp.testa")`. Also there are more sophisticated taggers in the nltk's toolkit than the ngram tagger (e.g. `HiddenMarkovModelTagger`, `PerceptronTagger`), but they take much longer to train.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212895/nltk-tag-dutch-sentence